# I get "undefined method" calling by Rails model, but works fine calling by Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive undefined method scan for User:Class when scan method 
(line 13: last = resp.headers['Link'].scan(/\d+/).last) 
is called by Rails User model (inside class method self.create_user(auth)) :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email
  field :nickname

  embeds_many :posts

  def self.create_user(auth)

    conn = FaradayStack.build 'https://api.example.com'
    resp = conn.get "/users/#{auth.nickname}/list"
    last = resp.headers['Link'].scan(/\d+/).last # <== error occurs here
    n = 0

    create! do |user|
      user.email = auth["user_info"]["email"]
      user.nickname = auth['user_info']['nickname']

      while n <= last.to_i do
        resp = conn.get "/users/#{auth.nickname}/list?page=#{n=n+1}"
        resp.body.each do |repo|
          user.posts.build( html_url: "#{repo['html_url']}",
                                         description: "#{repo['description']}",
                                         created_at: "#{repo['created_at']}",
                                         pushed_at: "#{repo['pushed_at']}",
                                         avatar_url: "#{repo['owner']['avatar_url']}" )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I call the same code by Rails console it works fine :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :158 > last = resp.headers['Link'].scan(/\d+/).last
 => "16" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :159 > last = resp.headers['Link'].scan(/\d+/).last.to_i
 => 16 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :160 >
```

Something related to istance and class method concept I guess, 
but I can't fix it.

UPDATE:

On suggestion of jimworm, I put rails logger instead of "offending" line :

```
Rails.logger.info "\r\n" + "#{Time.now} " + "resp.headers['Link']: #{resp.headers['Link']}" + "\r\n"
```

what I get is :

```
2011-09-30 16:40:03 +0200 resp.headers['Link']: 
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/
Completed 302 Found in 3151ms
MONGODB blumb_dev['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e85d4c41d41c8103f000006')})
```

while in Rails console it is :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :181 > resp.headers['Link']
 => "<https://api.example.com/users/lgs/list?page=18>; rel=\"next\", <https://api.example.com/users/lgs/list?page=51>; rel=\"last\"" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :182 >
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe `resp.headers['Link']` isn't what you think it is? Could be `nil` or something... spit it out in the log to find out.

Comment: The one that "errors" out yields a HTTP 302 but the "valid" one is from an HTTP 200. That seems weird.

Comment: Yeah that's your problem. You hit a redirect and it only gave you a redirect header, but none called 'Link'. `nil` doesn't have a `scan` method, hence the exception. *Why* it hit a redirect is an exercise for you, unless you were actually trying to access `https://api.example.com`, in which case we'll all have a quiet snicker to ourselves.

Comment: Yeah  :-)  ... If you swap that as an answer, I'll be happy to give you some 'bucks' ... then I'll look for what is happening with redirection ... may be I need better http responce error handling what you say ?

Comment: Answerified. Repwhoring'r'us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our hero was perplexed... it worked in the console, surely it'll work from the controller? The village will be doomed if the bug wasn't caught. He decided to take a snapshot of the bug, catch it in the act.

```
Rails.logger.info...
```

The trap was set, then he waited. The screen flashed. A hit! The bug has left its traces in our trap. Our hero looked and...

to his surprise, the trap was empty!

```
2011-09-30 16:40:03 +0200 resp.headers['Link']: #nothing here#
```

"Now how could that be" he wondered, "a bug that left no traces? What kind of bug leaves no traces?"

Then it came to him. "Eureka, a `nil`!" he smacked the table triumphantly, "a `nil` appears as nothing in the log! That's why I couldn't `scan` it!"

The identity of the bug was revealed, and it wasn't long before our hero traced it back to its home at `api.example.com` and mashed it once and for all. Turns out it was the messages that the village was sending to `api.example.com` that lured the bug out of hiding. Now with the bug gone, the village was saved and everyone lived in peace, happily ever after.